# I can't sync Master/Detail ListBoxes in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, dataset, master-detail

I'm having some problems syncing two ListBoxes in WPF.

I've created and populated a DataSet with two DataTables. One DataTable is for People and the other DataTable is for their Photos.

I can get both ListBoxes to function independently of each other, but I want them to function as a Master to Detail.

This is my first WPF project so any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

C# CODE:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
UserManagement.Users users = new UserManagement.Users(_cnFaces);
ds = users.GetUsersForFR();
users = null;
lbPeople.DataContext = ds;
lbPhotos.DataContext = ds;

    public DataSet GetUsersForFR()
    {
        Library.DAL.DataCE helper;
        try
        {
            string sSQLPeople = @"
                    SELECT 
                         *
                    FROM 
                        tblUsers
                    ";

            string sSQLPhotos = @"
                    SELECT 
                         *
                    FROM 
                        tblFacialRecognition
                    ";

            helper = new Library.DAL.DataCE(_cnFaces);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.Tables.Clear();
            ds.Tables.Add(helper.GetDataTable(sSQLPeople, CommandType.Text, "People"));
            ds.Tables.Add(helper.GetDataTable(sSQLPhotos, CommandType.Text, "Photos"));

            DataRelation relation = new DataRelation("People2Photos",
                ds.Tables["People"].Columns["fldUsername"],
                ds.Tables["Photos"].Columns["fldUsername"]);
            ds.Relations.Add(relation);

            return ds;
        }
        finally
        {
            helper = null;
        }
    }
```

DATATEMPLATES:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="PeopleTemplate">
        <StackPanel Margin="3">
            <DockPanel >
                <Image Source="{Binding fldPrimaryPhoto}" />
            </DockPanel>
            <DockPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding fldUsername}" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold" />
            </DockPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="PhotoTemplate">
        <StackPanel Margin="3">
            <DockPanel >
                <Image Source="{Binding fldPhoto}" />
            </DockPanel>
            <DockPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding fldUsername}" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold" />
            </DockPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

LISTBOXES:

```
<ListBox Name="lbPeople"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Tables[0]}"
         IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PeopleTemplate}"
         SelectionChanged="lbPeople_SelectionChanged" />
<ListBox Name="lbPhotos"
         Margin="0,0,326,0"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Tables[1]}"
         IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PhotoTemplate}" />
```

Comment: I don't know how to do this the DataTables. With objects need to bind the detail to the Element lbPeople SelectedItem.   Photos would be a List property of People.  It is worth going to List / ObservableCollections rather than DataTables.   The .NET collections  have so much power now.  Back in the days of arrays where you had to re-dimension to add an item there were more times to use DataTables.  Oh and populate your class with DataReader and get out of DataTables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should build a viewmodel that is more representative of your data.

Here is a suggestion:
Create a MainViewModel class, which will be the DataContext for your page.
MainViewModel will have an ObservableCollection< PersonViewModel > for the People.
Also, it will have a property SelectedPerson, which you will bind to the people list's SelectedItem.
Each PersonViewModel will have an ObservableCollection< PhotoViewModel > for that person's photos (and maybe a Name, or some other 'person' data).

Then, your xaml will look more like this:

```
<ListBox Name="lbPeople"
         ItemsSource="{Binding People}"
         IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PeopleTemplate}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<ListBox Name="lbPhotos"
         Margin="0,0,326,0"
         ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedPerson.Photos}"
         IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PhotoTemplate}" />
```

Because SelectedItem is 2-way bound to SelectedPerson property, **when you click a person in the first list, the second list will automatically update to show that person's photos**.

The properties that you bind to need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. You might want to do some research into [MVVM design](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) pattern. Once you get used to it, it really is the only way to do WPF. I would recommend checking out [MVVM-light](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/); it is not necessary but can make some viewmodel setup a little easier.

Comment: Now I have have something to look into. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I can't recommend MVVM Light enough, it's great!